# web2py cross applications global setting good practice

Tags: python, django, settings, web2py

I understand there is no such a thing like setting.py in Django for web2py . But is there a good place for these  global setting for web2py ?

I would like to put things like secret key, global constant and others.

Answer (score 0):

Although they might not work the same under the hood, you can still put your application-wide global setting inside this file applications/yourapp/models/0_whatever_name.py

Content in this file will be defined before (each) request reaches your app.

Or you can simply append your app-wide global definitions into applications/yourapp/models/db.py  By default it already contains lots of settings for this app.